# Xcode storyboard - can't drag to make constraint, items disappear when switch between size classes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, constraints

In my project I want the iPhone portrait version to stretch a view but the landscape and iPad version to have a specific width so it doesn't stretch since the iPad is wide and so is iPhone in landscape. The problem is, when I set one up, I switch to the other one and everything has disappeared. If I start dragging views from the left panel to the storyboard they appear again, but when I switch to the previous size class everything has disappeared on *that* one. I also can almost never drag on that ViewController's box to do what I want. For example, if I want to drag from a UIButton to the background of the layout it would normally bring up a menu with 'vertical spacing' etc but now it comes up with 'Outlets Delegate'.

How do I fix these issues? Nothing is working.

Comment: Could you post your storyboard screenshots, please?

Comment: I had lost the problem before you commented and couldn't recreate it for the screenshot. It's random. I solved it by deleting and re-adding everything. Very frustrating.

Comment: So now everything's OK?

Comment: @pedrouan Yes, everything's OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by deleting everything in the ViewController, re-adding everything in w-Any h-Any and adding specific constraints in the relevant size classes.